# How to pick NoSQL database with given constraints?

Tags: cassandra, amazon-dynamodb, couchbase, bigdata, nosql

Here are my requirements:

1. Average latency less than 8 ms, P95 latency less than 30 ms
2. Reads per sec: 15000K
3. Writes per sec: 100K
4. Cost: less than 500K $ per year
5. Operational cost: 10% of 1 dev time post production
6. Data size: 120 TB
7. Avg item size: 10 KB (overall it varies from 1 KB to 500 KB)

Nature of application:

- Write once in the beginning and then perform only reads (so no updates or deletes are involved hence can relax C in CAPs theorem)
- Data can be modeled into key-value pairs

Need help in picking database with these constraints. So far I have evaluated DynamoDB and MongoDB. DynamoDB fails in terms of cost and MongoDB fails in terms of operational overhead.

Comment: I think this question will result in a lot of opinion-based answers. Ideally you should do a POC of all the NoSQL databases (Cassandra, Couchbase, Mongo and Dynamodb)  that you think will suit your needs and test them to see if they meet your requirements. I would also advise  engage the Pre-sales team at each NoSQL company as they can help you get the most out of each database.

Answer (score 2):

A good choice would be running your own cluster of Cassandra - its performance is comparable with that of DynamoDB but you'll have the cost of managing multiple nodes yourself. Also, DynamoDB, I think, has a restriction of 400KB per item.